# Sequelize where with include

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, where-clause, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize as my backend ORM.
But I have a problem when I want "where" with a join table. The associations are good but I didn't know how to do for the "where".

This my code :

```
router.get('/id_presta_struct_unit/:id_presta_struct_unit', (req, res) => {
  models.structures.findAll({
    include: {
      required: false,
      model: models.structures_proposer_prestations,
      where: {
        id_presta_struct_unit: req.params.id_presta_struct_unit
      },
      include: {
        model : models.unites_facturation,
      }
    }
  }).then(data => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});
```

I got this request

SELECT * FROM `structures` AS `structures` LEFT OUTER JOIN `structures_proposer_prestations` AS `structures_proposer_prestations` ON `structures`.`id_structure` = `structures_proposer_prestations`.`id_structure` **AND `structures_proposer_prestations`.`id_presta_struct_unit` = '1'** LEFT OUTER JOIN `unites_facturation` AS `structures_proposer_prestations.unites_facturation` ON `structures_proposer_prestations`.`id_unite` = `structures_proposer_prestations.unites_facturation`.`id_unite`;

But i would like to get

SELECT * FROM `structures` AS `structures` LEFT OUTER JOIN `structures_proposer_prestations` AS `structures_proposer_prestations` ON `structures`.`id_structure` = `structures_proposer_prestations`.`id_structure` LEFT OUTER JOIN `unites_facturation` AS `structures_proposer_prestations.unites_facturation` ON `structures_proposer_prestations`.`id_unite` = `structures_proposer_prestations.unites_facturation`.`id_unite` **WHERE `structures_proposer_prestations`.`id_presta_struct_unit` = '1'**;

I don't know what to do I didn't find a post with the same problem

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

The associations

```
models.structures_employer_ressources.hasMany(models.ressources, { foreignKey: 'id_ressource' });
models.ressources.belongsTo(models.structures_employer_ressources, { foreignKey: 'id_ressource' });
```

The model of ressources

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('ressources', {
    id_ressource: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    }
 ........
  },{
    tableName: 'ressources',
    updatedAt: 'date_modification',
    createdAt: 'date_creation'
  });
};
```

And the model of structures_employer_ressources

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('structures_employer_ressources', {
    id_structure: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model :'structures',
        key: 'id_structure'
      }
    },
    id_ressource: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model :'ressources',
        key: 'id_ressource'
      }
    }
  },{
    tableName: 'structures_employer_ressources',
    updatedAt: 'date_modification',
    createdAt: 'date_creation'
  });
};
```

Comment: How are the models and associations defined? Please edit your question to include these, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I edited my post with the informations requested

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258158/how-to-implement-search-feature-using-sequelizejs/37326395#37326395

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3095#issuecomment-149277205

Answer (score 2):

If you feed an array into the where clause of the initial join, you can run a raw query against the joins.

Example:

```
 models.structures.findAll({
where:[["[structures_proposer_prestations].[id_presta_struct_unit] = " + req.params.id_presta_struct_unit, null]],
    include: {
      required: false,
      model: models.structures_proposer_prestations,
      where: {
        id_presta_struct_unit: req.params.id_presta_struct_unit
      },
      include: {
        model : models.unites_facturation,
      }
    }
  }
```

The array can also take in standard object syntax and will be combined by an AND. The null I am passing in is for paramaters, so It can definitely be optimised to take in the id as a paramater, just don't know the syntax off hand.