# Custom where with includes using SequelizeJS

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'd like to use the where conditions on including models but it doesn't work...

My code :

```
return this.context.OfferType.findAll({
 include: [{
   model: this.context.Offer,
   where: Sequelize.or(["description like '%"+search+"%'"],["name like '%"+search+"%'"]),
   include: [{
     model: this.context.OfferStore
   }]
 }]
});
```

My generated query :

```
SELECT `OfferType`.`id`, `OfferType`.`name`, `OfferType`.`createdAt`, `OfferType`.`updatedAt`, `Offers`.`id` AS `Offers.id`, `Offers`.`startDate` AS `Offers.startDate`, `Offers`.`endDate` AS `Offers.endDate`, `Offers`.`conditions` AS `Offers.conditions`, `Offers`.`description` AS `Offers.description`, `Offers`.`createdAt` AS `Offers.createdAt`, `Offers`.`updatedAt` AS `Offers.updatedAt`, `Offers`.`OfferTypeId` AS `Offers.OfferTypeId`, `Offers`.`OfferCategoryId` AS `Offers.OfferCategoryId`, `Offers`.`OfferStoreId` AS `Offers.OfferStoreId`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`id` AS `Offers.OfferStore.id`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`name` AS `Offers.OfferStore.name`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`logo` AS `Offers.OfferStore.logo`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`presentation` AS `Offers.OfferStore.presentation`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`mobilePhone` AS `Offers.OfferStore.mobilePhone`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`fixedLinePhone` AS `Offers.OfferStore.fixedLinePhone`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`fax` AS `Offers.OfferStore.fax`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`email` AS `Offers.OfferStore.email`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`website` AS `Offers.OfferStore.website`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`openingHours` AS `Offers.OfferStore.openingHours`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`createdAt` AS `Offers.OfferStore.createdAt`, `Offers.OfferStore`.`updatedAt` AS `Offers.OfferStore.updatedAt` FROM `OfferTypes` AS `OfferType` INNER JOIN `Offers` AS `Offers` ON `OfferType`.`id` = `Offers`.`OfferTypeId` AND (description like '%sport%' OR name like '%sport%') LEFT OUTER JOIN `OfferStores` AS `Offers.OfferStore` ON `Offers.OfferStore`.`id` = `Offers`.`OfferStoreId`;
```

`Name`is in the `OfferStore` table and `description` in the `Offers` table.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I want to achieve the exact same thing which is pretty standard for search but there doesn't seem to be anyone about for help with this stuff.

Comment: Found a half-solution that would work in this case. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258158/how-to-implement-search-feature-using-sequelizejs/37326395#37326395